# How to import multiple xml files into mysql table

Tags: mysql, xml

I have a multiple XML files in my remote server, the XML files has same structure. I want to load all the data into one mysql table. I have imported one XML file into mysql table but I need multiple XML data into one mysql table. Please provide me suggestions.

```
create procedure w()
begin declare row_index int;
declare xmlset longtext;
declare row_count int;
set row_index=1;
SET xmlset = LOAD_FILE("path/abc.xml"); 
set row_count  = extractValue(xmlset ,concat('count(','//entry',')'));
while row_index <= row_count do
insert into tbl_source20 (id,title,rank) values(
extractValue(xmlset , concat('/feed/entry[',row_index,']/id')),
extractValue(xmlset , concat('/feed/entry[',row_index,']/title')),
extractValue(xmlset , concat('/feed/entry[',row_index,']/snx:rank'))
);
set row_index = row_index + 1;
end while;
end
```

The above procedure is importing one XML file into mysql table. I have no idea to import multiple XML files into one Mysql table,provide me solution to do.

Comment: Do you also use a server side programming language like PHP?

Comment: No i'm not using PHP

Comment: Or anny other server side programming language?

Comment: I'm not using any server side programming language. I'm using only mysql to do the requirements

Comment: "I'm using only mysql to do the requirements " Ok then it's is not possible what you want to do, because you can't get a directory listing with MySQL queries..Unless you program your own UDF function which requires you to know how to program in C/C++ or use anny server side programming language to get the directory listing.

Comment: Ok Thanx for your reply

Comment: Is there any possible to create a looping in procedure to read the data inside the xml files. Because I have similar Name in XML file at the end of file name the ID may differ. e.g Name1, Name1 and so on...